# Angular two apps + Nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have two angular apps with routing that should be served via nginx.

First app should be served in the root of server, second - on subpath `project1`

So far I have:

**first** app routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FirstAppComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

**second** app routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'project1',
    children: [{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}]
  }
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12-alpine AS first-app
       # copy/npm install etc...

RUN ng build --prod

FROM node:12-alpine AS second-app
       # copy/npm install etc...

RUN ng build --prod --base-href /project1/


FROM nginx:1.19-alpine AS nginx

RUN mkdir /ui
COPY .docker/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=first-app /src/first-app/dist /ui
COPY --from=second-app /src/second-app/dist /ui
```

**nginx.conf**

```
    location / {
        root /ui/first-app/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /project1/ {
        root /ui/second-app/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }
```

So with such config when I go to root: `http://localhost/` it loads **first-app** which is OK.

When I go to `http://localhost/project1/` it shows blank page because it returns `index.html` for all static files:

[image]

From nginx logs:

```
192.168.48.1 - - [14/Jul/2022:09:23:55 +0000] "GET /project1/main.a98afec613a013921fda.js 
HTTP/1.1" 200 776 "http://localhost/project1/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

So it looks like nginx can't find `js` files and return last one in `try_files`. But I can't figure out why

**UPD**
when it's set `location /project1/` - it redirects automatically to root (first-app) when I go to `/project1/` URL

Comment: Did you try adding a final / in your second location ? (location /project1/ { )

Comment: @kipy, yes. It then redirects to root when I go to `project1`

Comment: You can handle both with regex : location ~ ^/project1(/.*)?$

Comment: @kipy, but they should point to different angular apps... `/` to first app `/project1/` to the second app. For some reason `/project1/` just redirects to first app... I have a feeling that Angular does thi redirect. I.e. `/project1/` is an unknown path to first app therefore redirected to root

Comment: By "both" I meant "/project1" and "/project1/" to both point to the second angular app. Your first rule (location /) tell nginx to redirect to index if the url is not a file or a folder. It means that "/project1", as it's not a real folder, will be included in that rule. That's why you go back to / when you set your second rule to /project1/. location ~ ^/project1(/.*)?$ is then the rule you have to use as your second rule. The first "location /" for your first app is OK

Comment: @kipy, it's after I've added slash. So second directive is `/project1/` and when I go to it in `localhost/project1/` it redirects to `localhost`...